# Python: Remove all characters outside of first curly braces

Tags: python, regex

If I have a string like so:

`text to remove { first text { group } { group2 } } more text to remove`

I want to specifically remove only the text that is not inside of the first curly braces to get something like so:

`{ first text { group } { group2 } }`

To do it in regex, I'm not sure how to specify for just the first iteration of curly braces, and not the nested ones.

Perhaps there is a easier way than using regex. The text  to remove can vary in length, though.

Comment: For text containing arbitrary number of nested parentheses, regex is not suitable and you should use a parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `search` and `group`:

```
>>> re.search('{.*}',s).group(0)
'{ first text { group } { group2 } }'
>>>
```

Or `findall`:

```
>>> re.findall('{.*}',s)[0]
'{ first text { group } { group2 } }'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of regex, you can also use `find` and `rfind`, which is more effective than regex.

```
str = 'text to remove { first text { group } { group2 } } more text to remove'
begin, end = str.find('{'), str.rfind('}')
filtered_str = str[begin: end+1]
print(filtered_str)
```